# Why can't we use variadic template at the beginning/middle of template specialization (and how to emulate)?

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates, template-meta-programming, template-specialization

I was wondering how to emulate the following:

```
template<class> struct foo; 

template<template<class..., int..., class...> class list,
class... clist1, int... ilist1, class... clist2>
struct foo<list<clist1..., ilist1..., clist2...>> {

};
```

This specialization (hypothetically) accepts a `class` with any number of classes, then integers, then classes. Currently there seems to be no way to directly implement this. (Bonus points if you can comment on why the standard doesn't support this)

An example of when this would be practical is in Eigen's linear algebra library where most classes are structures like:

```
Vector<class Scalar_type, int rows, class... options>
Mstrix<class Scalar_type, int rows, int cols, class... options>
```

With the above enabled, meta-template functions could be used that accept any of these base classes. Because it is not supported you have to write specializations for each class.

Is there any way to emulate a template function that supports accepting classes like the above?

I am looking for a generic solution. (Writing specializations for each class is not generic, and I am not directly looking for a solution to Eigen's library, that is just an example)

---

Example for clarification

Lets say I want to get the first class of a `template class`.
Somehow I get the original class type from some other meta-template function. Ergo I don't know what it's template parameters look like.

Maybe it's:

`Vector1<class Scalar_type, int rows, class... others>`
Or

`Vector2<class Scalar_type, class... others>`

Because I'm not directly using the type my meta template function must be of something like `template<class> struct foo;` with various specializations.

In this case `getFront` is a good example as I would need 2 specializations:

```
template<class> struct getFront; 

template<template<class...,int...,class...> class param, 
class... l1, int... l2, class... l3, class first> 
struct getFront<param<first, l1..., l2... l3....> { 
using type = first; };
```

and

```
template<template<class...> class param, class first, class... others>
struct getFront<param<first, others...>> {
using type = first;
};
```

Comment: The why is most likely a point of "Where do we stop?" The current rules prohibit some things that could work in theory, but they're also much simpler than you'd get with either a whole bunch of special cases or one or more complex generalizations of them.

Comment: Well in my opinion it seems like enabling these more complex specializations would enable a next-level sort of programming model within the c++ language. It would also make things like getting the last type in a list trivial. (just an example I know iterating through is still pretty trivial) IE:

`template<class..., class last> getLast { using type = last; };`

Comment: We seem to be moving to a constexpr-based metaprogramming model instead of a template-based one. There have also been other proposals that would help there, like parameter pack slicing.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any way to emulate a template function that supports accepting classes like the above?

What about using template specialization as follows ?

```
template <typename...>
struct foo;

template <typename ... Ts1, int ... Is, typename ... Ts2>
struct foo<std::tuple<Ts1...>,
           std::integer_sequence<int, Is...>,
           std::tuple<Ts2...>>
 {
 };
```

Or, if you prefer parametrize the template containers, something like

```
template <template <typename...> class Ct1, typename ... Ts1,
          template <int...> class Ci, int ... Is,
          template <typename...> class Ct2, typename ... Ts2>
struct foo<Ct1<Ts1...>, Ci<Is...>, Ct2<Ts2...>>
 { };
```

Comment: I am looking for a method that accepts a class of `class<class..., int..., class...>` 


Hypothetically the meta template function may be interested in `constexpr` fields or `using` declarations. In which case it must accept the actual class.


Using just a `template<class>` also prevents you from doing something like...


`template<class> struct getFront;`


`template<template<class...,int...,class...> class param, class... l1, int... l2, class... l3, class first> struct getFront<param<first, l1..., l2... l3....> {
using type = first; 
};`

Comment: (continued from above)

(hypothetically) this could be because I got the above class from another `using` decl and I don't know if the its of type `class<class...>` or type `class<class..., int... class>` therefor I don't have the luxary of being able to wrap all the template parameters in `std::tuples`

Comment: @JosephFranciscus - sorry but (maybe it's my fault: I'm bad with english) I don't understand what do you mean with your comments. Please, can you add they the question (so other interested can easily see it) with some examples of the code you want (or not) write?

Comment: Edited with example.

Comment: @JosephFranciscus - I see... I understand a little better but I suspect that what do you want is impossible with the actual language rules. Not that is unreasonable; only that C++11/14/17 doesn't support it.